# How to run a command in linux and use its output in another command?

Tags: linux

I want to subtract from the output of the `nproc` command and run another command using the calculated value.

The following doesn't work in linux:

`somecommand --set_cpus = (nproc - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
somecommand --set_cpus = `expr $(nproc) - 1`
```